# Routes not resolving in Production Environment (Rails 2.3.5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm deploying my app to a live server running passenger on Apache. I've tested the app locally and my routes appear sound. I have my public controllers under app/controllers/content and my admin controllers under app/controllers/admin.

Despite everything working in the development environment i'm getting "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." error when I request `http://mydomain.com/content/compare`. (i.e. `Content::CompareController#index`).

My production log contains the lines:
`Processing ContentController#compare (for 86.40.236.34 at 2010-08-14 15:03:15) [GET]`
`Authentication: session found, user_id is set`

`ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to compare. Actions: ):`

I've called rs.recognize_path 'content/compare' and I get the error:
`ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches "content/compare" with {}`

The same command works with my development machine however. I've tried adding the line 
`map.connect 'content/:controller/:action'` to the routes config file but this doesn't have any effect and I don't think it would be useful in the long run either.

Any advice on this? Seems strange that there are inconsistences between the Rails Environments.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your `routes.rb` file?

It appears that on your production machine it is trying to call the `compare` method in `ContentController`. Is this the method you want to be calling or is it `index`?

My guess is there is something wrong in your routes file. You can compare it on both environments by running `rake routes`.